# Is it mandatory to remove custom post or taxonomy on plugin deactivation?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin which registers a custom post type and custom taxonomy for that post type. Now, what to do once any one deactivates the plugin ? Should I de-register my custom post or taxonomy or any thing else ? I am totally new to plugin development kindly let me know what should i do on plugin deactivation ? Here is the code for my custom post type.

```
function portolfio_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Portfolio Post Type', 'Post Type General Name' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Portfolio Post Type', 'Post Type Singular Name' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Portfolio'),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type'),
        'archives'              => __( 'Portfolio Archives' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Portfolios'),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Portfolio'),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New'),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Portfolio' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Portfolio' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Portfolio' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Portfolio' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Portfolio' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image'),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image'),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into Portfolio'),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Portfolio'),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Portfolios list' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Portfolios list navigation'),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Portfolios list'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Portfolio' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Portfolio Post type to add portfolio of your work' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'portfolio_category'),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );

    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'portolfio_post_type', 0 );
```

I am just pasting this code inside my plugin file and on activation it creates custom post type fine, but I don't know what to do for this post type on deactivation of the plugin ... ? Any one to help me please ...

Also any good tips in plugin development would really be appreciated :)

Comment: Uninstall: Remove everything, your plugin added but after Deactivation do nothing (But if you want to do something then hide CPT menu or plugin related admin menu or options but don't delete plugin data on deactive)

Delete every thing on uninstall hook and if you want to do it try `$wpdb` custom query for clear your CPT data.

Comment: any hint to remove data or for action hook you are asking ??? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should delete all your code on plugin uninstall. For that you can create your `uninstall.php` file and place that file inside your main plugin directory. The code of your uninstall.php will look like shown below: 
Note: This is my plugin's `uninstall.php` file.

```
if ( ! defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) )
exit();

function go_delete_now() {
    global $wpdb;

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'films',
        'post_status' => 'any' ) );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ){
        wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true );
    }
}

go_delete_now();

// Set global
global $wpdb;
// Delete terms
$wpdb->query( "
    DELETE FROM
    {$wpdb->terms}
    WHERE term_id IN
    ( SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
        FROM {$wpdb->terms}
        JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}
        ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
        WHERE taxonomy = 'films_category'
    ) as T
    );
");
// Delete taxonomies
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} WHERE taxonomy = 'films_category'" );
```

Note: In my case my post type name is `films` and category for films is `films_category`.

You can simply change those post and taxonomy names as per your own needs and it will work fine for you. If any thing goes wrong let me know.

Comment: wow it worked like a charm ... thank you very much, I have idea about uninstall.php but never used before ... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can eventually convert your cpt posts as draft posts, on the uninstall action and add an admin notice.

Comment: I could not get your words please, can you provide a code snippet to work with ... as I already provided all my code snippet so it will be easy for your to provide me solution ... I am waiting badly for this please ...